# Updating labels with user input from MDTextField

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm trying to print user input from MDTextField to a label, but I keep getting "AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'".

Here's my python file:

'''

```
class TodoLayout(MDScreen, MDFloatLayout):
    pass


class CatLayout(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class BullyCat(MDApp, App):

    def get_data(self):
        user_input = (self.root.get_screen("to_do_view").ids.data.text)
        self.root.get_screen("to_do_view").ids.label_id.text = user_input

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("kivyfile.kv")

    def add_todo(self):
        global screen_manager
        screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        screen_manager.get_screen("main").todo_list.add_widget(TodoCard())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    BullyCat().run()
```

'''

Here's my .kv file:

'''

```
WindowManager:
    TodoLayout:
    CatLayout:

<TodoLayout>:
    name: "to_do_view"

    MDScreen:
        id: 'main'
        name: 'main'
        MDFloatLayout:
            md_bg_color: 0, 1, 0, .1
        MDLabel:
            text: "MyTasks"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .9, "center_y": .95}
            font_size: "35sp"
        MDLabel:
            id: date
            text: ""
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .885, "center_y": .89}
            font_size: "18sp"

        MDIconButton:
            icon: "plus"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .92, "center_y": .925}
            user_font_size: "30sp"
            md_bg_color: 30/255, 1, 30/255, 0.8
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
            on_release: on_release: root.ids.add_input.text = choice(app.my_list)

        MDIconButton:
            icon: "cat"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .075, "center_y": .925}
            user_font_size: "30sp"
            md_bg_color: 30/255, 1, 30/255, 0.8
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "cat_view"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

        MDTextField:
            id: data
            hint_text: "Write a task"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .1}
            size_hint: 0.5, None
        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: 'add'
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .8, "center_y": .1}
            on_release: app.get_data()

        MDLabel:
            id: 'label_id'
            text: 'Task 1'
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .9, "center_y": .8}
            font_size: 30



<CatLayout>:
    name: 'cat_view'

    MDScreen:
        id: 'second'
        name: 'second'
        MDFloatLayout:
            md_bg_color: 0, 1, 0, .1

        MDIconButton:
            icon: "pencil"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .075, "center_y": .925}
            user_font_size: "30sp"
            md_bg_color: 30/255, 1, 30/255, 0.8
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "to_do_view"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"

        MDTextField:
            hint_text: "Persistent helper text"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .1}
            size_hint: 0.5, None
```

'''

Ultimately i'm trying to build a to-do app with an animated cat that will bully you verbally into doing your tasks.

I suspect the problem lies within here:

```
def get_data(self):
        user_input = (self.root.get_screen("to_do_view").ids.data.text)
        self.root.get_screen("to_do_view").ids.label_id.text = user_input
```

I am very new to coding and i'm a bit lost here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's the error that you are getting. Could you show it please?

Comment: AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'

Answer (score 0):

Ids in your `kv` should not be enclosed in quotes. Just change:

```
id: 'label_id'
```

to:

```
id: label_id
```